# Issue with copying selected text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my function to copy the selected item from the select box and below that is the HTML code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#copy").click(function() {
                var selected = $("#basket").val();
                $("#ingredient").append(selected + '\n');
            });
        });
    </script>

    Basket
    <select size=3 class="form-control" name="basket" id="basket">
        <option value='apples'>apples</option>
        <option value='chicken'>chicken</option>
        <option value='potato'>potato</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    <center>
        <a id="copy" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Copy to Ingredients</a>
    </center>

    Ingredients
    <textarea rows=10 style="resize: none" class="form-control" id="ingredient" name="ingredient"></textarea>
```

I'm able to select and copy using the button. However, the issue I'm facing is that when the textarea is cleared manually and when the item is selected to copy using the button, it doesn't  work.

Any form of help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of `.val()`:

```
$("#copy").click(function(){
    var selected = $("#basket").val();
    $("#ingredient").val($("#ingredient").val() + selected+'\n');
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nQvqD/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#copy").click(function(){
    var selected = $("#basket").val();
    alert(selected);
    var x=$("#ingredient").val()+selected; 
    $("#ingredient").val(x);
});
```